# How to Convert a section of an Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, jsonconvert

I have collected a series of IP's in an array and would like to take those IPs and place them in a var so I can compare them to another string. It should be noted I'm pulling this code from a JSON package.

**EDIT:** Ok I may have miss-wrote the question. to be clear, all I'm struggling with is getting the value of 'ips' e.g. i tried this

```
var test = o365IpValues{id = "", ips = ""};
```

So i'd just like to create a value, that takes the values from IP so I can compare it to a table. That's all

Code:

```cs
var o365IpList = new[]
{
    new { id = 0, ips = new string[]{ } }
};
var o365IpVerion = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(o365IP, o365IpList);
```

Edit on my Edit: Here is a snipped of the JSON i'm converting

````
 {
   "id": 1,
   "serviceArea": "Exchange",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online",
   "urls": [
     "outlook.office.com",
     "outlook.office365.com"
     ],
   "ips": [
     "13.107.6.152/31",
     "13.107.18.10/31",
     "13.107.128.0/22",
     "23.103.160.0/20",
     "40.96.0.0/13",
     "40.104.0.0/15",
     "52.96.0.0/14",
     "131.253.33.215/32",
     "132.245.0.0/16",
     "150.171.32.0/22",
     "204.79.197.215/32",
     "2603:1006::/40",
     "2603:1016::/36",
     "2603:1026::/36",
     "2603:1036::/36",
     "2603:1046::/36",
     "2603:1056::/36",
     "2603:1096::/38",
     "2603:1096:400::/40",
     "2603:1096:600::/40",
     "2603:1096:a00::/39",
     "2603:1096:c00::/40",
     "2603:10a6:200::/40",
     "2603:10a6:400::/40",
     "2603:10a6:600::/40",
     "2603:10a6:800::/40",
     "2603:10d6:200::/40",
     "2620:1ec:4::152/128",
     "2620:1ec:4::153/128",
     "2620:1ec:c::10/128",
     "2620:1ec:c::11/128",
     "2620:1ec:d::10/128",
     "2620:1ec:d::11/128",
     "2620:1ec:8f0::/46",
     "2620:1ec:900::/46",
     "2620:1ec:a92::152/128",
     "2620:1ec:a92::153/128",
     "2a01:111:f400::/48"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "80,443",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Optimize",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "serviceArea": "Exchange",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online",
   "urls": [
     "smtp.office365.com"
   ],
   "ips": [
     "13.107.6.152/31",
     "13.107.18.10/31",
     "13.107.128.0/22",
     "23.103.160.0/20",
     "40.96.0.0/13",
     "40.104.0.0/15",
     "52.96.0.0/14",
     "131.253.33.215/32",
     "132.245.0.0/16",
     "150.171.32.0/22",
     "204.79.197.215/32",
     "2603:1006::/40",
     "2603:1016::/36",
     "2603:1026::/36",
     "2603:1036::/36",
     "2603:1046::/36",
     "2603:1056::/36",
     "2603:1096::/38",
     "2603:1096:400::/40",
     "2603:1096:600::/40",
     "2603:1096:a00::/39",
     "2603:1096:c00::/40",
     "2603:10a6:200::/40",
     "2603:10a6:400::/40",
     "2603:10a6:600::/40",
     "2603:10a6:800::/40",
     "2603:10d6:200::/40",
     "2620:1ec:4::152/128",
     "2620:1ec:4::153/128",
     "2620:1ec:c::10/128",
     "2620:1ec:c::11/128",
     "2620:1ec:d::10/128",
     "2620:1ec:d::11/128",
     "2620:1ec:8f0::/46",
     "2620:1ec:900::/46",
     "2620:1ec:a92::152/128",
     "2620:1ec:a92::153/128",
     "2a01:111:f400::/48"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "587",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Allow",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "serviceArea": "Exchange",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online",
   "urls": [
     "r1.res.office365.com",
     "r3.res.office365.com",
     "r4.res.office365.com"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "80,443",
   "expressRoute": false,
   "category": "Default",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 5,
   "serviceArea": "Exchange",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online",
   "urls": [
     "*.outlook.office.com",
     "outlook.office365.com"
   ],
   "ips": [
     "13.107.6.152/31",
     "13.107.18.10/31",
     "13.107.128.0/22",
     "23.103.160.0/20",
     "40.96.0.0/13",
     "40.104.0.0/15",
     "52.96.0.0/14",
     "131.253.33.215/32",
     "132.245.0.0/16",
     "150.171.32.0/22",
     "204.79.197.215/32",
     "2603:1006::/40",
     "2603:1016::/36",
     "2603:1026::/36",
     "2603:1036::/36",
     "2603:1046::/36",
     "2603:1056::/36",
     "2603:1096::/38",
     "2603:1096:400::/40",
     "2603:1096:600::/40",
     "2603:1096:a00::/39",
     "2603:1096:c00::/40",
     "2603:10a6:200::/40",
     "2603:10a6:400::/40",
     "2603:10a6:600::/40",
     "2603:10a6:800::/40",
     "2603:10d6:200::/40",
     "2620:1ec:4::152/128",
     "2620:1ec:4::153/128",
     "2620:1ec:c::10/128",
     "2620:1ec:c::11/128",
     "2620:1ec:d::10/128",
     "2620:1ec:d::11/128",
     "2620:1ec:8f0::/46",
     "2620:1ec:900::/46",
     "2620:1ec:a92::152/128",
     "2620:1ec:a92::153/128",
     "2a01:111:f400::/48"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "143,993",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Allow",
   "required": false,
   "notes": "Exchange Online IMAP4 migration"
 },
 {
   "id": 6,
   "serviceArea": "Exchange",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online",
   "urls": [
     "*.outlook.office.com",
     "outlook.office365.com"
   ],
   "ips": [
     "13.107.6.152/31",
     "13.107.18.10/31",
     "13.107.128.0/22",
     "23.103.160.0/20",
     "40.96.0.0/13",
     "40.104.0.0/15",
     "52.96.0.0/14",
     "131.253.33.215/32",
     "132.245.0.0/16",
     "150.171.32.0/22",
     "204.79.197.215/32",
     "2603:1006::/40",
     "2603:1016::/36",
     "2603:1026::/36",
     "2603:1036::/36",
     "2603:1046::/36",
     "2603:1056::/36",
     "2603:1096::/38",
     "2603:1096:400::/40",
     "2603:1096:600::/40",
     "2603:1096:a00::/39",
     "2603:1096:c00::/40",
     "2603:10a6:200::/40",
     "2603:10a6:400::/40",
     "2603:10a6:600::/40",
     "2603:10a6:800::/40",
     "2603:10d6:200::/40",
     "2620:1ec:4::152/128",
     "2620:1ec:4::153/128",
     "2620:1ec:c::10/128",
     "2620:1ec:c::11/128",
     "2620:1ec:d::10/128",
     "2620:1ec:d::11/128",
     "2620:1ec:8f0::/46",
     "2620:1ec:900::/46",
     "2620:1ec:a92::152/128",
     "2620:1ec:a92::153/128",
     "2a01:111:f400::/48"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "995",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Allow",
   "required": false,
   "notes": "Exchange Online POP3 migration"
 },
 {
   "id": 8,
   "serviceArea": "Exchange",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online",
   "urls": [
     "*.outlook.com",
     "*.outlook.office.com",
     "attachments.office.net"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "80,443",
   "expressRoute": false,
   "category": "Default",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 9,
   "serviceArea": "Exchange",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online",
   "urls": [
     "*.protection.outlook.com"
   ],
   "ips": [
     "40.92.0.0/15",
     "40.107.0.0/16",
     "52.100.0.0/14",
     "52.238.78.88/32",
     "104.47.0.0/17",
     "2a01:111:f403::/48"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "443",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Allow",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 10,
   "serviceArea": "Exchange",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Exchange Online",
   "urls": [
     "*.mail.protection.outlook.com"
   ],
   "ips": [
     "40.92.0.0/15",
     "40.107.0.0/16",
     "52.100.0.0/14",
     "104.47.0.0/17",
     "2a01:111:f400::/48",
     "2a01:111:f403::/48"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "25",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Allow",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 11,
   "serviceArea": "Skype",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
   "ips": [
     "13.107.64.0/18",
     "52.112.0.0/14",
     "52.120.0.0/14"
   ],
   "udpPorts": "3478,3479,3480,3481",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Optimize",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 12,
   "serviceArea": "Skype",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
   "urls": [
     "*.lync.com",
     "*.teams.microsoft.com",
     "teams.microsoft.com"
   ],
   "ips": [
     "13.107.64.0/18",
     "52.112.0.0/14",
     "52.120.0.0/14",
     "52.238.119.141/32",
     "52.244.160.207/32",
     "2603:1027::/48",
     "2603:1037::/48",
     "2603:1047::/48",
     "2603:1057::/48",
     "2620:1ec:6::/48",
     "2620:1ec:40::/42"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "80,443",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Allow",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 13,
   "serviceArea": "Skype",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
   "urls": [
     "*.broadcast.skype.com",
     "broadcast.skype.com"
   ],
   "ips": [
     "13.107.64.0/18",
     "52.112.0.0/14",
     "52.120.0.0/14",
     "52.238.119.141/32",
     "52.244.160.207/32",
     "2603:1027::/48",
     "2603:1037::/48",
     "2603:1047::/48",
     "2603:1057::/48",
     "2620:1ec:6::/48",
     "2620:1ec:40::/42"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "443",
   "expressRoute": true,
   "category": "Allow",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 14,
   "serviceArea": "Skype",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
   "urls": [
     "quicktips.skypeforbusiness.com"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "443",
   "expressRoute": false,
   "category": "Default",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 15,
   "serviceArea": "Skype",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
   "urls": [
     "*.sfbassets.com",
     "*.urlp.sfbassets.com",
     "skypemaprdsitus.trafficmanager.net"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "80,443",
   "expressRoute": false,
   "category": "Default",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 16,
   "serviceArea": "Skype",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
   "urls": [
     "*.keydelivery.mediaservices.windows.net",
     "*.msecnd.net",
     "*.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net",
     "ajax.aspnetcdn.com",
     "mlccdn.blob.core.windows.net"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "443",
   "expressRoute": false,
   "category": "Default",
   "required": true
 },
 {
   "id": 17,
   "serviceArea": "Skype",
   "serviceAreaDisplayName": "Skype for Business Online and Microsoft Teams",
   "urls": [
     "aka.ms",
     "amp.azure.net"
   ],
   "tcpPorts": "443",
   "expressRoute": false,
   "category": "Default",
   "required": true
``` },
I did try to use an array in a separate. The reason why i changed it to anonymous was that the value was not being sent across. I ended up with 114 empty values with nothing in them. So, after conversing with my team. i tried this.
````

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Can you add some test cases please with expected input/outputs?

Comment: What's the problem? What does `o365IpVerion` contain? Without the JSON string it's impossible to test your code. There may be a misspelling or missing property.

Comment: Please post your actual JSON data. And you don't need to use anonymous-types - you'll find things a LOT easier if you use named classes.

Comment: Please add an example of what your JSON looks like.

Comment: Hi everyone. i've added a bit of the JSON I wanted to deserialize. I did try to do it with named classes but for some reason it only sent across null values. i had 145 instances of 0 or null. Thats why i changed to anonymous. so the values would pass.